Trouble with Gnosis Safe Multi-signature Contract Transaction Execution in Unity Using Nethereum
I'm working on a blockchain integration for a Unity project using Nethereum to interact with a Gnosis Safe L2 multi-signature contract. The goal is to add a new owner to the safe.
Here's what I've done so far:

Propose Transaction: I can propose a transaction to add a new owner using the addOwnerWithThreshold function. but it always gives failure on the scan.

Sign Transaction: I attempt to sign the transaction using the contract's signTransaction function.

Execute Transaction: After signing, I try to execute the transaction with the execTransaction function.


However, I'm encountering an issue with retrieving a valid transaction hash. I get a SmartContractRevertException: Smart contract error: GS031 when trying to estimate the gas required for execution. Additionally, the scan results show the transaction as failing.
Here’s the code snippet I'm using to propose and sign the transaction:
public async Task<string> ProposeAddOwnerTransactionAsync(string newOwnerAddress, BigInteger threshold)
{
    var contract = web3.Eth.GetContract(userAccountABI, userAccount.contractAddress);
    var addOwnerFunction = contract.GetFunction("addOwnerWithThreshold");
    var gasPrice = await web3.Eth.GasPrice.SendRequestAsync();
    var gas = new HexBigInteger(5000000);
    var transactionHash = await addOwnerFunction.SendTransactionAsync(WalletsBackground.primaryAccount.Address, gas, gasPrice, null, newOwnerAddress, threshold);
    return transactionHash;
}

public async Task<string> SignTransactionAsync(string txHash)
{
    var contract = web3.Eth.GetContract(userAccountABI, userAccount.contractAddress);
    var signTransactionFunction = contract.GetFunction("signTransaction");
    var signedData = await signTransactionFunction.CallAsync<string>(txHash);
    return signedData;
}

The error occurs when I use the EstimateGasAsync. Here are the details of the exception:
SmartContractRevertException: Smart contract error: GS031

I've reviewed the contract's ABI, and it seems like everything should be working correctly. However, I'm unable to proceed.
Questions:

Is there something I'm missing when estimating gas for this transaction?
Could there be an issue with the transaction signature or the way the transaction is being constructed?
Any tips for handling errors like GS031 when working with multi-signature contracts using Nethereum?

Any help or insight into how to properly execute this type of transaction would be greatly appreciated!
Additional Information:

Unity version: 2022.3.34f1
Nethereum version: 4.19.2
Solidity contract ABI functions:

[
  {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "owner",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "_threshold",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "addOwnerWithThreshold",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "bytes32",
                "name": "txHash",
                "type": "bytes32"
            }
        ],
        "name": "signTransaction",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "bytes",
                "name": "",
                "type": "bytes"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
     },
     {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "value",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "bytes",
                "name": "data",
                "type": "bytes"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "enum Enum.Operation",
                "name": "operation",
                "type": "uint8"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "safeTxGas",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "baseGas",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "gasPrice",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "gasToken",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address payable",
                "name": "refundReceiver",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "bytes",
                "name": "signatures",
                "type": "bytes"
            }
        ],
        "name": "execTransaction",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "bool",
                "name": "",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "payable",
        "type": "function"
      }

